# How can i change class of a button dynamically using its id or name Angular 2/ionic 3 using [ngClass]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to change the class name by its id/name of button. in the below code i am getting the result by using jQuery but in some cases it will not work. is there a better way to do this using angular/ionic. please help me if anybody knows a better way to do this.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.AppService.touchScreenContent.subscribe(screencontent =>{
        let value = screencontent;
        var firstCaseValue = value[0];
        var innerCaseValue = value[1];
        switch (firstCaseValue) {
            case "0x02040100":
                this.Watchchange.touchScreenReceived('3');
                this.commonAudioGet(innerCaseValue);
                break;
        }
    }
}
public commonAudioGet(value) {
    var aud2INNER = value;
    console.log("innte VALUEREC" + value);
    for (let r in aud2INNER) {
        console.log("streamingValue" + r);
        console.log("streamingValue" + aud2INNER[r]);
        if (r != '0x00012006') {
            switch (aud2INNER[r]) {
                case 0:
                    console.log("RvalueCASE0" + r);
```

> Here " r " is button ID

```
                    $('#' + r).removeClass().addClass('btnforAudio');
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $('#' + r).removeClass().addClass('btnforAudio orange');
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            $('#' + r).prop("value", aud2INNER[r]);
        }
    }
}
```

> below is my html code which i am trying to change the button class with button id. the ID looks complex because i am getting this value from a web-socket call.

```
<div id="0x02040100" class="form-group" *ngIf="this.showValue==7">
  <h5 class="h5-text">AUDIO LINE</h5>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <div>
          <button ion-button block color="primary" name="0x02040500"  (tap)="AppService.sendNotifyOnTouchAD($event,'0x02040500','0x00011003','1')" id="0x00011003" value=1 >PFL</button><br>
        <br><br>
          <button ion-button block color="primary" name="0x02040500"  (tap)="AppService.sendNotifyOnTouchAD($event,'0x02040500','0x00011005','1')" id="0x00011005" value=1 >CH ON</button><br>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <div>
          <input type=range orient="vertical" min=0 max=31 value=5 name="0x02040500" step=1 id="0x00012006" (change)="AppService.sendNotifyOnTouchAudio($event)" onchange="rangevalue.value=value">
          <output class="h3-text" id="rangevalue"></output>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</div>
```

Comment: How many buttons do you have in the template? Can you show us your template, please?

Comment: @hgoebl hi thanks for your reply. i have updated my question. there are lots of button like the one i copied above. i have function to show/hide few depending on the condition. is there a way to do this

Comment: It's unclear how you initialize the component and if your buttons are created dynamically or are listed statically in the template. I'm afraid we can't help you without you providing much more context (source). Please format your code in a way we can read it.

Comment: why are you trying to use JQuery to modify the DOM instead of using angular data binding for the values?

Comment: @hgoebl Hi i updated my question to explain my complete need. Can you help me now

Comment: @Claies but i don't know how do i  directly change class with the button ID. can you help me. i googled it but no where i found angular to do the same with a button id/name

Comment: I guess I'm as confused as others here;  what does "change class name with button ID" mean?  what do you **expect** the class output to look like?  I'm relatively positive that you can get any combination you want with the `[className]` directive or `[ngClass]`....

Comment: @Claies Sorry for making confusions, my simple requirement is to change the button color and shape with the button ID. here in my code "r" in the loop is the Button ID's.

Comment: It seems like you are thinking about this the wrong way.  Instead of trying to search the DOM for IDs, why not use an array to store the class names for each button and then bind `ngClass` to the appropriate array element?  then you just need to update the value in the array element.

Comment: @Claies Thank you for the answer. I am sorry if am asking same question again. when i get the responds from the web-socket request i will get only button ID and a value of 0/1. 0 means the button is in OFF stage. 1 means the button is ON stage. how can i do this using an array if i have a lots of button in the same format. can you give me a hint of code. your help will save my life

Comment: @Claies Hi Can you help me on this